# Javascript - split string by regex {{...}}

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, split, mustache

I have a string like the following:

```
My name is {{Name}} and my favorite States and Cities are: {{#each Places}}{{State}}{{City}}{{/each}}
```

I would like to split the items into an array where the delimiter is in this form {{...}} tag, i.e. text surrounded by double braces.

So in the example about my array would be:

```
ary[0] = 'My name is ' ;
ary[1] = '{{Name}}';
ary[2] = ' and my favorite States and Cities are: ';
ary[3] = '{#each Places}}';
ary[4] = '{{State}}';
ary[5] = '{{City}}';
ary[6] = '{{/each}}';
```

Then I want to combine everything from {{#...}} to the next instance of {{/each}}

so that ary[3] to ary[6] become one block of text:

```
{{#each Places}}{{State}}{{City}}{{/each}}
```

Could someone help me devise the regex and 'combiner' logic?

Here's what I have so far:

```
//Split string into array
var ary = str.split("{{SPLIT_BY_MUSTACHE_TAG_REGEX_HERE}}");

var collectionString = '';
var inCollection = false;

//Iterate through array 
$.each(ary, function( index, value ){

//Check if currently in a collection: {{#each...}} to {{/each}})
if(!inCollection) {

//Check if current value matches start of collection tag
if(value.match({{#START_OF_COLLECTION_REGEX_HERE}}) {
    inCollection = true; 
    collectionString += value; //Append value to string

} else {
    //Not at start of or inside a collection

    //Do something with open text or standalone tag: {{...}}       
}

} else {
    //Currently inside a collection

    //Append to collection string
    collectionString += value;

    //Check if end of collection: {{/each}}
    if(value.match({{/END_OF_COLLECTION_REGEX_HERE}})
        inCollection = false;
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `string.match` instead of `string.split` function.

```
> var st = "My name is {{Name}} and my favorite States and Cities are: {{#each Places}}{{State}}{{City}}{{/each}}"
undefined
> st.match(/\{\{.*?\}}|.+?(?=\{{|$)/g);
[ 'My name is ',
  '{{Name}}',
  ' and my favorite States and Cities are: ',
  '{{#each Places}}',
  '{{State}}',
  '{{City}}',
  '{{/each}}' ]
```

- `\{\{.*?\}}` Matches all the strings which are enclosed within two curly braces like `{{..}}`.
- `|` Regex alternation Operator or logical OR operator usually used to combine two regex patterns.
- `.+?(?=\{{|$)` Matches any charcater one or more times upto the `{{` braces or end of the line anchor.

Comment: I started with http://jsbin.com/qetuqodupu/2/edit , but I was stuck at `{{#each Places}}` since it's both `{{..}}` and have ` space`....any fix ?

Comment: You can improve the pattern by `/{{[^}]*}}|[^{}]+/g`

Comment: yes, but what if op wants to match  also the strings like `{{foo{bar}foo}}`

Comment: Then OP should state that.

Comment: I would start [here](http://www.splusbook.com/RIntro/RCourse.pdf). R is a hard language to learn but once you know the basics it gets alot easier.

Comment: I'd use `[\s\S]` for the second part since templates are usually multiline, that is `/{{.*?}}|[\s\S]+?(?={{|$)/`